# Convert float values to uint8 array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, uint16, uint8array

I have a Float32Array with values from an audio file.I want to save it as a .wav file so I need to convert that values to a Uint8array.

To convert from uint8 to float I convert first to an int16 array and then to a Float32Array ([Convert int16 array to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177712/convert-int16-array-to-float/46179552#46179552))
How can I do that conversion in the other direction?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert to an `ArrayBuffer`, copy the data into and then create a byte view of this buffer :

```
var data = new Float32Array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]);

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.byteLength);
var floatView = new Float32Array(buffer).set(data);
var byteView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

This function can convert any TypedArray to any other kind of TypedArray :

```
function convertTypedArray(src, type) {
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(src.byteLength);
    var baseView = new src.constructor(buffer).set(src);
    return new type(buffer);
}
```

Example :

```
convertTypedArray(new Float32Array([0.5, 0.3, -0.1]), Uint8Array);
```

#### Edit

As Ian pointed out in the comment section, you can access the `ArrayBuffer` with `TypedArray.buffer`, so you can simply do :

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(floatArray.buffer);
```

Note that doing this, `byteArray` and `floatArray` will share the same buffer, so modifying `byteArray` will modify `floatArray` and vice versa.

Comment: You could even reuse the buffer if you wanted. `return new type(src.buffer)`.

Comment: this is amazing! thank you so much for this. improved my onderstanding of buffers

Comment: If you have `const floats = new Float32Array([1.53, 1000.5])`, using `new Uint8Array(floats)` will give you `[1, 232]`, so be careful. Only in certain circumstances will you want your floats to be wrap back around 255. i.e. 232 was gotten by doing `1000-256-256-256`

Comment: I don't think the Note applies as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/buffer says "The buffer property is an accessor property whose set accessor function is undefined, meaning that you can only read this property" which is quiet annoying