# get double hash result like js-sha1 library in c#

Tags: c#, hash, double, sha1

I try to hash a double (1529480427715.5532) with SHA1 algorithm and i have this hash in c#:

- use in string format: "3e8f41233f90a85f9963afaa571ba76afb8bb08d"
- use in double format: "c880857c399c7b9cc9c6395197e700543c400b17"

but in fact i want to get this hash "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709" as result like when i'm using [js-sha1](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1) library.

Comment: The hash "da39a3e..." in js-sha1 is the hash of empty strings/empty arrays. Are you sure that you want that hash?

Comment: It seems to me that you are not correctly hashing your double from the javascript side. But why would you want to hash a double in the first place? Doubles *do* have precision errors, so I'm wondering what your use case is

Comment: Some code i have  generate above hash. I have seen mentioned js library generate it. You can re produce it by using that library (js-sha1)

Comment: Post the code you used. As mentioned by @xanatos js-sha1 does *not* support numbers, you would have to convert it to a string or byte array first....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197487/613130) code to convert from `float64` (that is `double` in C#) to `Uint8array`, you can:

```
// c880857c399c7b9cc9c6395197e700543c400b17
var hash = sha1(convertTypedArray(new Float64Array([1529480427715.5532]), Uint8Array));
```

or even shorter, without using that link, because `sha1` accepts `ArrayBuffer` as a parameter:

```
var hash = sha1(new Float64Array([1529480427715.5532]).buffer);
```

Note that `sha1` accepts only some types of input, `number` isn't one of them.

From the [examples](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1) of the library it seems strings, `Array`, `Uint8Array`, `ArrayBuffer` are supported.

As written by @Freggar,

```
// da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
var hash = sha1('');
```

And, using strings:

```
// 3e8f41233f90a85f9963afaa571ba76afb8bb08d
var hash = sha1('1529480427715.5532');
```