# How to *reverse* JavaScripts DataView?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, floating-point-conversion, uint8array

### I understand this question is oddly phrased, so let me explain with 2 examples.

**Example 1**
The code below turns the series of values `[64, 176, 0, 86, 68, 97, 136, 8]` into the float `4096.336980910979`.

```js
(new DataView(new Uint8Array([64, 176, 0, 86, 68, 97, 136, 8]).buffer)).getFloat64();
/*Output 4096.336980910979*/
```

How do I *reverse* it to get the series of values `[64, 176, 0, 86, 68, 97, 136, 8]` when I input the float `4096.336980910979`?

**Example 2:**
The code below turns the series of values `[70, 253, 192, 0]` into the float `32480`.

```js
(new DataView(new Uint8Array([70, 253, 192, 0]).buffer)).getFloat32();
/*Output 32480*/
```

How do I *reverse* it to get the series of values `[70, 253, 192, 0]` when I input the float `32480`?

Comment: May be this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196990/convert-float-values-to-uint8-array-in-javascript

Comment: @Tushar, unfortunately that did not help because that is conversion between two different TypedArrays rather than conversion of numbers to and from TypedArrays :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have created a solution!**

Float 32 solution:

```js
var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(4); /*Create an Array Buffer (Blank)*/
var floatArray = new Float32Array(arrayBuffer); /*Use the Float32 instance of the Buffer*/
var uintArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer); /*Use the Uint8 instance of the Buffer*/

floatArray[0] = 32480; /*Define a value to the Float32Array*/
/*In order to correctly access the Uint8Array, it must be reversed for some reason?!*/
var newUintArray = uintArray.reverse();
var newarr = (new DataView(newUintArray.buffer)).getFloat32();
```

The variable `newarr` should equal 32480 and the variable `newUintArray` can be used to access the *reversed dataview*.

Float 64 solution:

```
var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var floatArray = new Float64Array(arrayBuffer);
var uintArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

floatArray[0] = 30543;
var newUintArray = uintArray.reverse();
var newarr = (new DataView(newUintArray.buffer)).getFloat64();
```